# Can't print Name instead of Id from Foreign Key

Tags: django

I have a model Batting which has stats in a particular player.  The player info is in Master which is related by foreign key in Batting.

```
class Batting(models.Model):
    player = models.ForeignKey(Master)
    year = models.IntegerField()
    homeruns = models.IntegerField()
    ...

    def __unicode__(self):
        #return "%s %s %s" % (self.player.name_first, self.player.name_last, self.team)
        return "%s %s" % (self.player.name_first, self.player.name_last)


class Master(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=30, primary_key=True)
    name_first = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    name_last = models.CharField(max_length=30, db_index=True)
    ...

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s %s" % (self.name_first, self.name_last)
```

I have two queries:

```
home_runs = Batting.objects.filter(year=max_year['year__max']).order_by('-homeruns')[:20]
home_runs_all_time = Batting.objects.values('player').annotate(hrs=Sum('homeruns')).order_by('-hrs')[:20]
```

The first lists the 20 top home run hitters in 2013.  The second involves .values() and .annotate() to produce the sum of Homeruns by each player and list them.  The first works fine in my template:

```
<h2>Most Home Runs in a Season -- {{ year }}</h2>
<table>
    <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Homeruns</th>
    </tr>
    {% for p in home_runs %}
    <tr>
    <td>{{ p }}</td><td>{{p.homeruns}}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>

<h2>Most Home Runs All Time</h2>
<table>
    <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Homeruns</th>
    </tr>
    {% for p in home_runs_all_time %}
    <tr>
    <td>{{ p.player }}</td><td>{{p.hrs}}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

But the html in the second prints the FK id instead of the name:
Most Home Runs in a Season -- 2013

```
Name    Homeruns
Chris Davis 53
Miguel Cabrera  44
Pedro Alvarez   36
Edwin Encarnacion   36
```

Most Home Runs All Time

```
Name    Homeruns
bondsba01   762
aaronha01   755
```

How can I make the second query return the **unicode** value from the Master table instead of the key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
Batting.objects.values('player', 'player__name_first', 'player__name_last').annotate(category=Sum(category_name)).order_by('-category')[:20]
```

The 3 value arguments identify a unique person in the table.  category_name is a field.  I was lucky in this case that all three values are unique together, and I want to display the names even though the player (which is a foreign key) is enough to identify the grouping

Answer (score 2):

I think you should try like :

```
home_runs_all_time = Batting.objects.values('player__name_first', 'player__name_last').annotate(hrs=Sum('homeruns')).order_by('-hrs')[:20]
```

in template:

```
<h2>Most Home Runs All Time</h2>
<table>
    <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Homeruns</th>
    </tr>
    {% for p in home_runs_all_time %}
    <tr>
    <td>{{ p.player__name_first }} {{ p.player__name_last }}</td><td>{{p.hrs}}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't work.  I'm thinking it has to do with the .values() method since without that method the top home runs for a specific year works fine.  (see both queries)

Comment: the above should work. Tested something similar on my machine. Make sure you copied it the same way